# Open GL ES 1.1 and iPhone games

Tags: iphone, opengl-es

Will iPhone games that draw 2D textures like this:

```
glPushMatrix();
glTranslatef(xLoc, yLoc, 0);
[myTexturePointer drawAtPoint:CGPointZero];
glPopMatrix();
```

work with newer iPhones (that support OpenGL ES 2.0)?  I'm asking because I just learned OpenGL ES 2.0 doesn't support glPushMatrix etc.

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The newer phones still support the older OpenGL ES 1.1, so this code should run fine, as long as you're running it in a 1.1 context.

Answer (score 1):

Newer iphones do support both standards. So your code should work.

> To maintain compatibility with the
>   OpenGL ES 1.1 used in existing iPhone
>   and iPod touch devices, "the graphics
>   driver for the PowerVR SGX also
>   implements OpenGL ES 1.1 by
>   efficiently implementing the
>   fixed-function pipeline using
>   shaders," sources report. This
>   indicates that games and other
>   applications unique to the iPhone 3G S
>   and other future models of the iPhone
>   and iPod touch are likely to arrive
>   that will either be exclusive to the
>   new model, or more likely, will
>   support improved 3D graphics on the
>   new device while still working on
>   previous models using the older
>   fixed-function 3D pipeline.

[Source](http://www.appleinsider.com/articles/09/06/09/iphone_3g_s_to_use_powervr_sgx_gpu_core_for_opengl_es_2_0.html)